# Don't work get element by id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get to this ID (contentContainer) in a webpage:

```
... //code before is OK, i can get values, etc. Then comes this:

<!-- *********************** CONTENT BELOW ************************** -->
    <table align="center" id="contentContainer" width="100%">
```

It seems I can't get to this part of the code (after that line with CONTENT BELOW). I tryed to use the code in Tampermonkey:

```
var a= document.getElementById("contentContainer").length;
console.log(a);
```

I can use this kind of var check to the code before that code, without any problem. Any Ideas of whats happening and how to get the code I want (in contentContainer)?

Comment: A DOM node doesn't have a `.length` property. A node list does.

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which has no length property so you'll get `undefined` in the console.

Comment: You need to change the title of your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single DOM node doesn't have a `.length` property. A node list, which is an array-like collection of HTML elements does.

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById("contentContainer");  // Get a reference to the single table node
console.log(tbl);                                       // Log what was refererenced

// Get a reference to all of the row elements in the table
// (which returns a node list).
var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll("tr");
console.log(rows.length);  // Log how many nodes are in the node list
```

```html
<table align="center" id="contentContainer" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Without other information it seems that your call to get the element by Id is trying to get the length property at the same time which will fail to get the element in the first place. So try getting rid of the .length.

Comment: The element reference will be gotten successfully and then the `.length` property will be attempted, which will fail.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It wont technically fail, it just returns `undefined`.

Comment: @DJDaveMark No, it won't throw an error, but yes, it will technically fail to find a property called `.length` anywhere along the prototype chain, so, yes, `undefined` will be returned as a result.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry I meant to address that to `ProgrammerAdept`